# How to use Power Shell to add web part in share point page?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

i have a problem in adding web part in empty page via share point online

no error appears but no updated done in page

page test is empty page at sharepoint online and check in too

after multi times for searching to add web part i  have the following code

```
function AddWebPartToPage ($ctx, $sitesURL) {

    $pageRelativeUrl = "/Pages/test.aspx"
    $wpZoneID = "Left"
    $wpZoneOrder= 0

    $WebPartXml = [xml] "
    <WebPart xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2'>
        <Title>User Properties</Title>
        <FrameType>None</FrameType>
        <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
        <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
        <ZoneID>QuickLinks</ZoneID>
        <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
        <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
        <Height />
        <Width />
        <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
        <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
        <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
        <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
        <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
        <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
        <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
        <DetailLink />
        <HelpLink />
        <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
        <Dir>Default</Dir>
        <PartImageSmall />
        <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
        <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
        <IsIncludedFilter />
        <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
        <Content xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor'><div>test 2019</div></Content> 
        <PartStorage xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor' />
    </WebPart>"

    try{

        Write-Host "Starting the Process to add the User WebPart to the Home Page" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        #Adding the reference to the client libraries. Here I'm executing this for a SharePoint Server (and I'm referencing it from the SharePoint ISAPI directory, 
        #but we could execute it from wherever we want, only need to copy the dlls and reference the path from here        
        Add-Type -Path '*************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path '****************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

        Write-Host "Getting the page with the webpart we are going to modify" -ForegroundColor Green

        #Using the params, build the page url
        $pageUrl = $sitesURL + $pageRelativeUrl
        Write-Host "Getting the page with the webpart we are going to modify: " $pageUrl -ForegroundColor Green

        #Getting the page using the GetFileByServerRelativeURL and do the Checkout
        #After that, we need to call the executeQuery to do the actions in the site
        $page = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($pageUrl);
        $page.CheckOut()
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        try{

        #Get the webpart manager from the page, to handle the webparts
        Write-Host "The page is checkout" -ForegroundColor Green
        $webpartManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

        Write-Host $WebPartXml.OuterXml

        #Load and execute the query to get the data in the webparts
        Write-Host "Getting the webparts from the page" -ForegroundColor Green
        $ctx.Load($webpartManager);
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        #Import the webpart
        $wp = $webpartManager.ImportWebPart($WebPartXml.OuterXml)


        #Add the webpart to the page
        Write-Host "Add the webpart to the Page" -ForegroundColor Green
        $webPartToAdd = $webpartManager.AddWebPart($wp.WebPart, $wpZoneID, $wpZoneOrder)

        $ctx.Load($webPartToAdd);
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Errors found:`n$_" -ForegroundColor Red

        }
        finally{
            #CheckIn and Publish the Page
            Write-Host "Checkin and Publish the Page" -ForegroundColor Green
            $page.CheckIn("Add the User Profile WebPart", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
            $page.Publish("Add the User Profile WebPart")
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-Host "The webpart has been added" -ForegroundColor Yellow 

        }   

    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Errors found:`n$_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}

 $tenantAdmin = "****@***.com"
 $tenantAdminPassword = "****************"
 $secureAdminPassword = $(convertto-securestring $tenantAdminPassword -asplaintext -force)
 $siteURL = "https://"*****************.com/sites/****************/*********";
 $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
 $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($tenantAdmin, $secureAdminPassword)  
 $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

######################################
# Set Add WebPart to Page Parameters #
######################################
$relUrl = "/sites/****************/*********"
AddWebPartToPage $ctx $relUrl
```

the expected from the above code that page will include div having

test 2019

but it didn't appear

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to add webpart to Sharepoint online page would be using PnP Powershell 
You could use below command to add webpart to page

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl $serverRelativeUrlOfPage -Xml $webPartXML -ZoneId $zoneId -ZoneIndex $zoneIndex
```

More details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpwebparttowebpartpage?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: The term 'Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program

Comment: You need to PnP module first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps